# My API is not showing any pk of rental model

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-1.9

why my api is not showing any pk of rental model? I have used tastypie for rest api. Id of gallery model is shown but not of rental model.This is my code for api

```
class RentalResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):
    gallery = fields.ToManyField('rentals.api.api.GalleryResource', 'gallery', related_name='rental',full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Rental.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rental'
        detail_uri_name = 'slug'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        fields = ['listingName','id','slug','property','city','place','ownerName','room','water','amenities','price','summary','phoneNumber','email']
        filtering = { "property" : ALL , "id":All, "city":ALL, "place":('exact', 'startswith',), "room":ALL,"price":ALL,"listingName":ALL,"slug":ALL}
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()


class GalleryResource(ModelResource):
    rental = fields.ForeignKey(RentalResource, 'rental',full=False, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Gallery.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'gallery'
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Comment: Isn’t the pk field really called `id` in django?

Comment: I tried using id but did not show id so i tried using pk.

Comment: Please show Your `Rental` model definition

Answer (score 0):

Because You have `detail_uri_name = 'slug'` in `RentalResource`. Remove this line.